# 404 Response from Image on Android

Tags: android, capacitor

I'm relatively new to Capacitor, however have been developing with Cordova for the last 10 years.

Everything is going great so far, I’m just having one small issue with my Android platform.

I have some images hosted on a HTTPS domain that are returning 404 errors on Android only. Do I need a Whitelist plugin for this? I thought Whitelist was no longer required? The images are on HTTPS, so I don’t think its a cleartext issue.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated, nobody seems to want to respond to my question on the Capacitor Discord or Forums.

Regards,
Matt

---- Edit for Reference

- I have added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to `AndroidManifest.xml`
- All images are HTTPS not HTTP
- Works perfectly fine on iOS
- Added `img-src *` to `index.html` Content-Security-Policy
- External images load from Cloudinary sources, but not from my eCommerce store domain (Both HTTPS and both work in WebView and iOS)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this issue.

When setting the `server: { hostname: "" }` setting in `capacitor.config.json` make sure that the domain in there does not match the domain of the external source you are trying to load data from. It appears that if it does match the Capacitor app attempts to load the resources locally instead.